# Can I assign the folder name from form records in application.hyperlink?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have all folders for clients named using the same file naming rubric.  I can use application.hyperlink to open the main folder, but can I use this code to open a subfolder with data from the form records?

Application.FollowHyperlink "w:\main folder\"

Comment: Yes, but an example of your data would help, are you doing this from a form with the data presented on it ? More information required really.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I am doing this from a form with the client data presented.  Each of the clients has a dedicated file folder named based of their ID which is a data field on the form.  I would like to open their specific folder.  Another way may be to open the main folder and then populate the windows explorer search bar with their client ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have a text box control on your form called txtClientId.
Using the data in that in vba you concatenate that into your hyperlink string;

```
Dim sPath as String

sPath = "W:\Main Folder\"
sPath = sPath & Me.txtClientId & "\"

Application.FollowHyperlink sPath
```

I would avoid using a mapped drive letter if possible, much more reliable to use the network share URL as it's not dependent on being set up on the end users local machine. Something like

```
 \\DataServer\MainShare\....
```

Comment: Would there be a way to insert the txt.ClientId into the search bar in windows explore after the applicaiton.followhyperlink commancd?

Comment: You could using code similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004097/from-vba-run-a-search-in-explorer-within-a-designated-folder but I would ask why?  If there is a possibility that the folder doesn't exist, simply test for it using the Dir() command, and/or possibly better still, create it first if it's missing, then open it.